# Logic for verifying major and minor version requirements?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Lets say a server requires a minimum client version.

There is a major and minor version, for example:

```
1,0 1,2 2,0 2,9
```

Given a function such as:

```
bool checkVersion(int minimumMajor,int minimumMinor,int clientMajor, int clientMinor) {
//TODO
}
```

What would the implementation look like?

The logic is basically

```
return clientMajor.clientMinor >= minimumMajor.MinimumMinor
```

But making floats out of ints seems inefficient. What might be a fast way to do this logic.

Thanks

Comment: C or C++?  They're different languages.

Comment: Wouldn't lexical string comparison do well?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity A C or C++ implementation is fine, as long as it is fast.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't do lexical string comparison or floating point conversion. Because it is a common bug in version comparisons. Version 4.10 is a newer version than 4.9

Comment: @Milo `as long as it is fast`  For a string like that, you won't notice any difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, you have to be doing this comparison several million times a second for it to get on your profiler.  And if you're doing that on code that checks your version number, you probably need to revisit your structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
if (clientMajor > minimumMajor) return true;
else if (clientMajor == minimumMajor && clientMinor >= minimumMinor) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: This is the best plain C answer.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity We're going to assume that `true` and `false` were `#define`d then :)

Comment: Haha, totally missed that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the C++ standard library and your compiler's optimizations.

```
#include <tuple>

bool checkVersion(int minimumMajor, int minimumMinor, int clientMajor, int clientMinor) {
    return std::make_tuple(clientMajor, clientMinor) >= std::make_tuple(minimumMajor, minimumMinor);
}
```

Comment: You beat me by several seconds, and `make_tuple` and `tie` compile to the same instructions in this case with full optimizations.  So I'm withdrawing my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Same here :) Upvoted, I wonder whether `std::tie` is ever better (or worse) for this comparison. By looking at their definitions it seems they perform equally well.

Comment: It's definitely better in cases where you're passing non-trivial structures in by reference.  Imagine that `minimumMajor` is an arbitrary precision int that's several megabytes large (for whatever reason).  You want to avoid that copy.  And the compiler might not be able to prove that it doesn't have side effects.

Comment: Oh, ok, right, make_tuple will copy in that case (unless you move into it).

Answer (score 1):

Check the major version first. If they're equal, then check the second. Otherwise, you don't have to bother with the minor version.

Alternatively, if you assume that major versions never get above some number (say 1024) you could do this:

```
(minimumMajor*1024)+minimumMinor < (clientMajor*1024)+clientMinor
```

Or, even more efficiently:

```
(minimumMajor<<10)+minimumMinor < (clientMajor*1024)+clientMinor
```

Comment: `minimumMajor*1024` and `minimumMajor<<10` will be compiled to the same instruction on any decent compiler... (and most terrible ones)